# PHP mangles my dates

Tags: php, date

```
$doba = explode("/", $dob);

$date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0, $doba[0], $doba[1], $doba[2]));
```

The above code turns any date i pass through into 1999-11-30 and i know it was working yesterday. Date is correct when I echo $doba. Anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: You need to show us the values you are passing in as $dob for us to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the format of `$doba`? Remember `mktime`'s syntax goes hour, minute, second, **month, day year** which can be confusing.

Here's some examples:

```
$doba = explode('/', '1991/08/03');
echo(date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0, $doba[1], $doba[2], $doba[0]);

$doba = explode('/', '03/08/1991');
echo(date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0, $doba[1], $doba[0], $doba[2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

or even easier: `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dob))`

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit overkill to use `mktime` in this case. Assuming `$dob` is in the following format:

> `MM/DD/YYYY`

you could just to the following to acheive the same result (assuming `$dob` is always valid):

```
$doba = explode("/", $dob);
$date = vsprintf('%3$04d-%1$02d-%2$02d', $doba);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with what jcoby said above, the [strptime](http://www.php.net/strptime)() command gives you more control by allowing you to specify the format as well.